# How to get split along with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have one column in a database table containing state data like `33:Rio de Janeiro`. I want to extract the code `33` using a LINQ expresion. Here is my code.

```
public string command(string query)
{
    string res = string.Empty;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnect());
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
    res = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
    return res;
}
```

Here I want to get the code of the state.

```
string code = db.command("select cidade from logos ")
                .Split(':')
                .Where(<Expression to get the first part>);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string code=db.command("select cidade from logos ").Split(':').First()
```

Comment: You can also use `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: In general `FirstOrDefault` would be a bad choice in situations like this because if the input is malformed and you get zero elements you would silently continue execution with a `null` reference and probably cause an error some time later. If you expect that there is one element use `First()` because this immediately throws an exception and makes the problem obvious if there is no element in the sequence. In this specific code an empty string will cause this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this:

```
string code=db.command("select cidade from logos ").Split(':').First()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx):

```
string code = db.command("select cidade from logos").Split(':').First();
```

Or simply get first item by index:

```
string code = db.command("select cidade from logos").Split(':')[0];
```